# SQL Invalid group function

Tags: mysql

I want to select the columns with the max number of canceled trip. I know how to count the number of trips using the SQL statement, however, when I try to use the max function it gives the invalid group function error.
my SQL statement is as below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0kKb.png)

```
select t.ServiceNumber, t.RouteNumber, remark,
       max(count(if(Cancelled =1 ,1,null))) as"Total Cancelled Trip"
from trip t inner join
     route r 
     on r.ServiceNumber = t.ServiceNumber and
        r.RouteNumber = t.RouteNumber
group by t.ServiceNumber, t.RouteNumber,remark;
```

Comment: If there are many max values and i want to show all the columns that share the same max value without using the limit. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one row with the maximum, you can do:

```
select t.ServiceNumber, t.RouteNumber, remark,
       count(*) as "Total Cancelled Trip"
from trip t inner join
     route r 
     on r.ServiceNumber = t.ServiceNumber and
        r.RouteNumber = t.RouteNumber
where Cancelled = 1
group by t.ServiceNumber, t.RouteNumber, remark
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Getting all such rows in the event of ties is tricky in MySQL.  Perhaps the easiest way uses variables:

```
select tr.*
from (select t.ServiceNumber, t.RouteNumber, remark,
             count(*) as "Total Cancelled Trip",
             (@maxtct = greatest(@maxtct, count(*))
      from trip t inner join
           route r 
           on r.ServiceNumber = t.ServiceNumber and
              r.RouteNumber = t.RouteNumber cross join
           (select @maxtct := 0) params
      where Cancelled = 1
      group by t.ServiceNumber, t.RouteNumber, remark
     ) tr
where `Total Cancelled Trip` = @maxtct;
```

Comment: thank you, but i have not learnt how to use a variable in my course as i am a beginner. Is there any other way to show other columns with the same maximum value ?